# How to disable summernote (angular-summernote)?

Tags: angularjs, summernote

I am using angular-summernote. How to disable that?

```
<div summernote class="summernote" ng-model="postData.content" placeholder="Content"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put a div over the element that is transparent. it will blur the elemtnand makes it un accessable to user.

Comment: Not working..like this

I tried

Like this

      <div ng-disabled="activeTab === 'all'">
        <div summernote class="summernote" ng-model="postData.content" placeholder="Content"></div>
      </div>

Comment: you have to create a div that will cover the element its not disabling exactly but its kinda disable the user to use the element.
<div ng-show="isElementShown" class="properclasstocovertheelement"></div>

Comment: I know that, but sometimes you can not disable a component that is developed to be a standalone applicaiton. I faced that problem while using drawIO in my applicayion and i had to use a overlay div to block the user.

Answer (score 1):

It can be solved like this. It's kinda hacky but it does the job and ensures that text and images cannot be altered in the disabled state. With this solution everything rendered in the editor stays as the editor should show it.

```
$timeout(function(){
   angular.element('.note-editable').attr('contenteditable', false);
   angular.element('.note-control-selection').remove();
},0);
```

Answer (score 0):

> WORKAROUND: Just add `ng-if` to hide that tag and show another textarea
>   insted.

Comment: This is good plan. But can I disable summernote instead of adding other?

Comment: by 'disable' do you still mean to show the summernote but just in disabled state?

Comment: can you provide a fiddle, i'm not able to find one!

Answer (score 0):

If you have a single summernote element, then you may probably use this:

```
$(". summernote").siblings(".note-editor").find(".note-editable").attr("contenteditable","false");
```

This portion is the one where the user can write content.

Comment: By default it is loading as contenteditable= "true". I am using angularJS in place of JQuery

<div class="note-editable" contenteditable="true" data-placeholder="Content">dark</div>

Comment: @Donthamsettivbhadrarao: that's what is enabling the user to type any content. Changing the value to false will disable the user to perform any action, basically disable the editable field.